# Getting UnboundLocalError while executing the program

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a code for an application in Python. So far I have written this. I am getting an error at line 68 i.e. shopping_list = shopping_list.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True). The error message is given right after the code. I need to make a list where I am appending all the items added to the cart.

```
import sys

class Shopping:
    
    def add_item(self):
        items = int(input('Enter the number of items you want to send'))
        for i in range(0, items):
            print('Enter the details for the item')
            type_pack = input('Enter the type(letter or parcel):')
            weight = input('Enter the weight of the product: ')
            destination = input('Enter the destination of the product: ')
            zone = countries_zones.loc[countries_zones['Destination'] == destination.capitalize(), 'Zones'].iloc[0]
            zone1 = int(zone[-1])
            cost = 0
            if type_pack.lower() == 'parcel':
                if float(weight) < 3:
                    cost = parcel_by_sea_dataset[zone][parcel_by_sea_dataset.Weight == 'Over 2.5 kg up to 3kg'].iloc[0]
                    if cost == '-':
                        print("Sorry, no parcel services available for ", destination)
                    print('The cost of your stamp is', cost)

                elif 3 <= float(weight) < 5:
                    cost = parcel_by_sea_dataset[zone][parcel_by_sea_dataset.Weight == 'Up to 5kg'].iloc[0]
                    if cost == '-':
                        print("Sorry, no parcel services available for ", destination)
                    print('The cost of your stamp is', cost)

                elif 5 <= float(weight) < 10:
                    cost = parcel_by_sea_dataset[zone][parcel_by_sea_dataset.Weight == 'Up to 10kg'].iloc[0]
                    if cost == '-':
                        print("Sorry, no parcel services available for ", destination)
                    print('The cost of your stamp is', cost)

                elif 10 <= float(weight) < 15:
                    cost = parcel_by_sea_dataset[zone][parcel_by_sea_dataset.Weight == 'Up to 15kg'].iloc[0]
                    if cost == '-':
                        print("Sorry, no parcel services available for ", destination)
                    print('The cost of your stamp is', cost)

                elif 15 <= float(weight) < 20:
                    cost = parcel_by_sea_dataset[zone][parcel_by_sea_dataset.Weight == 'Up to 20kg'].iloc[0]
                    if cost == '-':
                        print("Sorry, no parcel services available for ", destination)
                    print('The cost of your stamp is', cost)

                else:
                    print("please enter a number between 0-20")
            print('Please chose the option below')
            print('1. Add to cart')
            print('2. Go back')
            selection = input('Enter your choice: ')
            if selection == '1':
                temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Item Type': [type_pack],
                                        'Weight': [weight],
                                        'Destination': [destination],
                                        'Cost': [cost]})

                shopping_list = shopping_list.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
                print(shopping_list)

    def delete_item(self):
        pass

    def amend_item(self):
        pass

    def print_list(self):
        pass

    def print_receipt(self):
        pass
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Divyam Projects/oops1/stamp.py", line 114, in <module>
    mainMenu()
  File "C:/Divyam Projects/oops1/stamp.py", line 99, in mainMenu
    shopping.add_item()
  File "C:/Divyam Projects/oops1/stamp.py", line 68, in add_item
    shopping_list = shopping_list.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shopping_list' referenced before assignment
```

Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the shopping list and append something to it, but it was never created.
try this:

```
shopping_list = []
shopping_list.append(something,ignore_index=true)
```

you can declare the shopping_list above your class

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

```py
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shopping_list' referenced before assignment
```

This means you are attempting to do something with a variable that doesn't exist yet. The solution is to declare it before you try to use it, probably directly below the line where you declare `items` in this function.

Another problem will arise: `.append()` has no return value, so `shopping_list` will become `None` if you assign the return value of `.append()` to it. In fact, `.append()` modifies the list in-place; there is no need to assign anything when appending.

Clarification:

```py
# Incorrect
foo = []
foo.append('bar')
# foo is now None

# Correct
foo = []
foo.append('bar')
# foo is now ['bar']
```